# shortcode not parsing on custom template

Tags: wordpress, parsing, shortcode

I am trying to get display-posts shortcode to work on my wordpress. It is not parsing (displaying as [display-posts] )  on the actual live page. Does anyone know how to resolve this. I am using a custom template I think that might have something to do with it. I read some mention of adding some lines to function.php file? Anyone know how to resolve this, I would appreciate any help.

Thanks!!

Comment: Do you have the [Display Posts Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/display-posts-shortcode/) installed?

Comment: I do, and I tried activating and deactivating all the pluings, which is why I think it is the template.

Comment: What version of WordPress and Display Posts are you using?

Comment: wp is 3.8.1 and the plugin is 2.3